# How to get the right date with SUtime?

Tags: java, stanford-nlp, sutime

I have a Strings like this one for example: 
**" I will meet you on Jun 12 and give you your 1500 "**
The result i got is **2** dates BUT I ONLY NEED THE JUN 12:
**JUN 12 [from char offset 14 to 20] --> 2017-06-12

1500 [from char offset 40 to 44] --> 1500-XX-XX**

Also if there wasn't a space between **Jun and 12** (**Jun12**), SUtime doesn't get the date
How can i proceed?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you have found some of the errors that SUTime will produce.  I'll note both of these issues, but I am not sure there is a quick fix to address them.